# Java PreparedStatement and Alter Table syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, sqlexception

I have to create an index on a field of a table using PreparedStatement. The query that I've to perform is the following:

```
ALTER TABLE esa_matrix ADD INDEX doc_index (id_doc)
```

So, I've create a `PreparedStatement` instance with the same text of the query and perform `executeUpdate()` method on it. But at execution time I get a SQL syntax error.
This is creation of the `PreparedStatement` instance:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("ALTER TABLE "+ESATable+ "ADD INDEX doc_index ("+idDocLabel+")");                                  
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
```

This SQLException I get:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'doc_index (id_doc)' at line 1
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance,
Antonio

Comment: i encourage you to use String.format() for this kind of "stringconstruction" not just for DB-querys. `String query = String.format("ALTER TABLE %s ADD INDEX doc_index (%s)", ESATable, idDocLabel);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've forgotten a space before the "ADD".

Comment: Easy mistake to make, if I had a pound for every time I'd done that I'd be a rich man :)

Comment: As an aside, as it's a prepared statement, couldn't you use ps = conn.prepareStatement("ALTER TABLE ? ADD INDEX doc_index ?"); and then use ps.setString(1,"ESATable") etc. Not sure if it's permissible, but if it is, it certainly makes the statement a lot easier to read and debug.

Comment: @user53300: Parameters won't work when you're specifying table names, sadly.